Why apt install node 12 in Ubuntu 22.04 and not the latest lts version? And How can i install the LTS or any other version using APT?
I'm building the Debian installer for my Node js app, so in dependencies function I'm using the nodejs. When I check the nodejs or node version It's showing the node 12.22.9 version.
sudo apt install nodejs

And when I check the version of nodejs
node -v
v12.22.9

Is there any way that I can install the nodejs v18.20.3 LTS or any other version using apt?


This is not really a programming problem, but rather one about the decision making of the distro maintainers.
The short answer is: you can't.
The long answer: you'd have to add the PPA to the sources list in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/, but I'm not sure that should be done from within a package as it may break other things on the system - that's what LTS releases are there for - to be stable (albeit at times going with antiques). So you really shouldn't modify other people's system default from that PPA.
Consider creating a snap or dockerising it ...

Or just install NVM and deal with it that way.

Again: I don't think that's a reasonable approach to take on behalf of others ... ;)

Thanks @tink for the quick help. so, What's the approach should i follow to create node base full stack app for the Linux system. Is there any way to isolate environment like XAMPP or LAMP stack do? they are isolating the db env, and other dependencies. it is possible for node base app. like my app only uses nodejs come with my installer or installer through my app.  Actually I've nest js and Angualr based app for that, I'm creating the desktop application.

That sounds like a lot of decisions to make on others behalf - I'd definitely go down the route of docker (or similar) to accomplish that and bundle everything your app needs (or, if you can handle the internal comms between components, several containers that communicate via tcp/ip ...) @ParthPatel
